# how to install canon pixma mg 7150 printer

Tags: printing, canon

I tried to install my new printer: canon pixma mg7150(printer/scanner) on ubuntu 12.04 LTS but till this moment it doesn't work.
The operating system recognize the printer, but cannot find the right drivers.

Maybe someone can help me with this problem?

Thanks ahead,

Louis.

Answer (score 0):

I can print wirelessly to my Canon MG7150 printer from ubuntu 12.04, but only after installing the driver from Canon at http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG7150.aspx?type=download&page=1
Get the Debian package archive, run the install.sh script inside it from a terminal. Then use the normal Printing app in ubuntu to find the printer on the network. It should pick up the driver you've now installed.
The one problem I haven't solved is how to scan with this printer wirelessly... I'll raise a separate post for that...